# How to create a while loop in c++ without numbers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a C++ program that:

1. asks "Question?(a/b)"
2. reads a character variable from input
3. If the value of the variable is a, prints "You chose a!"
4. If the value of the variable is b, prints "You chose b!"
5. In other cases, prints "You must answer a or b", and starts again with the first question.

I wrote:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    main()
    {
       char c = A, a, b, B;

       cout << "Question?(a/b)" << endl;
       cin >> c;

       while ("You must answer a or b") {
           cin >> c;
       }
       if ( c = A || a )
           cout << "You chose a!" << endl;
       if ( c = B || b )
           cout << "You chose b!" << endl;
   }
```

I know that the parts with "if" are totally wrong, but I don't understand how to do...

Comment: I know that you may think that I'm not making any effort because these things seem easy to you, but I am and it's really hard! SO please, instead of downgrading my question could you help me?

Comment: Please don't ask others to do **your** assignment.

Comment: I have tried to do it on my own but as you can see it doesn't work! I don't why people on this site never want to help...

Comment: Check your course book on how to write `if`. This `if ( c = A || a )` is wrong, for more than one reason. Ah wait, your `while` is also totally out of whack. Uh... start again on page 1 maybe?

Comment: The title does not even match the body of the question.

Comment: This code seems to have problems in almost every statement. Let's start from the beginning. Can you explain (I mean, describe in detail, as much as possible, your understanding of) the statement you wrote '`char c = A, a, b, B;`'...?

Comment: Have you tried to compile the code? What errors and warnings did the compiler print?

Comment: Please enable _all_ compiler warnings, and learn the language first instead of programming by guessing. The only things right in this code are the `cin` and `cout` lines.

Answer (score 3):

The truth value of the string `"You must answer a or b"` never changes. What you want to check is the value of `c` and insure that it is either `a` or `b`. You could accomplish this like with `while(c != 'a' && c != 'b')`

Also for your if statements, you are using variable that does not exist or are not initialized. `a`, `B` and `b` are not initialized, while `A` does not exists. Either way you don't need them.

Additionally the `||` operator does not work like that. You need a truth value on each side. Thus you should do something like `if(c == 'a' || c == 'b')`

Comment: Actually, variables `a, b, B` do exist. Anyway variable `A` does not exist, so the initializer `c = A` should not even compile...! (But OP probably does not realize it.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, this code should help you:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    char c;

    do {
        cout << "Choose 'a' or 'b' (to quit enter 'q'):" << endl;
        cin >> c;
        if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'b'))
        {
            cout << "You chose " << c << endl;
        }
    } while (c != 'q');

    return 0;
}
```